# Adding custom HTTP headers to vstudio 2012 web service proxy

Tags: c#, http, service, web, header

I need to call a web service and have added a service reference to my project in VS2012. I can call it but have a requirement to add custom HTTP headers to the call (not SOAP headers)

any help on how to get this working would be appreciated

mike

Answer (score 0):

Use the OperationContext.OutgoingMessageHeaders collection to add your custom header.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.outgoingmessageheaders.aspx